# Does inf_mr refresh (xaringan) when I change the css file in RStudio?

Tags: css, r, rstudio, xaringan

This is my Rmd code:

````
---
title: "example"
author: "Example"
date: "02/03/2021"
output: html_document
css: "style2.css"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(xaringan)



```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown  Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R ffgfghfghfhewqewqweqeMarkdown seesaSASsSAasdgf <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
asSSAsS
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

And this my my CSS file code:

```
.container-fluid{
  border:  25px solid lightblue;}
```

I thought that when I change/edit and then save the CSS file the Html output produced by Rmarkdown would be updates as well. But its not hapenning.

Is there any way to refresh the html after update/edit the CSS file?

Or the refresh provided by `xaringan::inf_mr()`  requests that I save the Rmd file after edit/update the CSS file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inf_mr()` is only able to detect changes in the document being rendered. One way to deal with this is to include the css in a css chunk while you are writing your slides, then more than to a separate file afterward.

````
---
title: "example"
author: "Example"
date: "02/03/2021"
output: html_document
css: "style2.css"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(xaringan)
```

```{css}
.container-fluid{
  border:  25px solid blue;}
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown  Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R ffgfghfghfhewqewqweqeMarkdown seesaSASsSAasdgf <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
asSSAsS
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: By default, it should watch for changes in CSS files: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/1cca62540fe20b15a72adace2579f9c53376d36b/R/render.R#L294-L298 If it doesn't, it might be a bug. Please feel free to report to the Github repo yihui/xaringan. Thanks!